# AWS allow any user of a specific account to send messages to a queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am trying to configure the SQS policy for a queue to authorize all principles of an account to send messages to this queue, according to the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#principal-accounts):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "sqspolicy",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "Sqs policy1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": { 
          "AWS": [
            "arn:aws:iam::123456789:root"
          ]
        }
        "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:123456789:my_queue"
      }
    ]
}
```

Will this allow any principle of this account to send messages to my_queue or will it only allow the root user?

Or should I use the below policy with a condition instead?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "sqspolicy",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "Sqs policy1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": { 
          "AWS": "*"
        }
        "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:123456789:my_queue"
        "Condition": {
          "StringEquals": {
            "AWS:SourceAccount": "123456789"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says:

> When you use an AWS account identifier as the principal in a policy, you delegate authority to the account. All identities inside the account can access the resource if they have the appropriate IAM permissions attached to explicitly allow access. This includes IAM users and roles in that account.

According to this, your first approach will allow all of your users to send messages.

Comment: And the second one will all all existing AWS accounts to access your queue, which may not be what you want.

Comment: @petrch How come? There is `AWS:SourceAccount` condition.

Comment: aha, I missed that, so forget about my comment, it's nonsense then.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought, just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Only first policy is **valid**. The second policy will not work, the way you may think. The reason is that [aws:SourceAccount](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-sourceaccount) is only used for `service-to-service requests`, not IAM users or roles. The most common example of when `aws:SourceAccount` is used is for S3:

> For example, when an Amazon S3 bucket update triggers an Amazon SNS topic post, the Amazon S3 service invokes the sns:Publish API operation. The bucket is considered the source of the SNS request and the value of the key is the account ID associated with the bucket.

Send-messages requests made by IAM users/roles in the second account **will be denied** because for these entities there is no `aws:SourceAccount`.

Comment: Thank you. That is good to know, I wasn't aware of that